# How to adjust the size of a TextView so that the text is the same scale across all devices

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I set the text size of a TextView so that regardless of whether it is running on a tablet or a low-res phone, it will still always occupy the same height. I am currently trying:

```
public float adjustSP(float sp) {
    Resources r = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources();
    float density = r.getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return sp / density;
}
```

And then, when I create the text view:

```
 TextView textView = new TextView(activity);
 textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 60.0f);
 textView.setText(message.getMessage());
 textView.setLayoutParams(new ScrollView.LayoutParams(ScrollView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ScrollView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

But the results are inconsistent and, to be honest, kind of weird. On a tablet it is the right size - roughly 1/3 of the screen for a moderate amount of text, however on a Nexus S emulator it is enormous - basically 1 word per screen.

Comment: You can use this library also : https://github.com/intuit/sdp . It is very easy to use and just put your textsize,margin and padding it will automatically handle this.

Answer (score 1):

For text view text-size never use "dp", instead use "sp". 
Also using dimens.xml for different devices of android will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Android supporting multiple screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
I also recommend you to not hard code your UI elements widths/heights

Comment: Thanks, I've referred to it (actual, I've read it in the past but I re-read it in case I was missing something). It doesn't at all answer the question of why the above code is not achieving density-independence. Also, there is no hard coding of width/heights in the above code. Sure, I could move the SP into a resource, but lets stay on topic, OK? Maybe I'll do that when it works at a basic level.

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries that do this for you if you want to try something for example [autofittextview](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview)

Comment: I think you kind of get what I want, but it is slightly different. Auto-fitting text to a text view is a related but different problem. It's not that I have a potentially variable sized text view that I want to fit into, it's that I want the size of the text in my text view to always be the same percentage of the display.